# What's the easiest and most efficient way to combine UDP and RPCs in java?

Tags: java, networking

I'm currently considering using java in one of my projects(for reasons unrelated to networking). At the moment I'm using C++ and a custom protocol built on top of UDP. My problem here is that while the added efficiency is nice for sending large amounts of realtime-data, I'd rather have something along the lines of RPCs for pure "logic actions" such as login. RPC's in C++ are hard to do though, since standard C++ itself has no notion of serialization.

In another answer, I found Java's RMI, which seems to be similar to RPCs, but I couldn't find how efficient/responsive it is, nor whether it could be plugged into my existing UDP socket, since I don't want to have two ports open on my server program.

Alternatively, since I think Java has serialization, I could implement RPC's myself, depending on how straightforward deserializing an arbitrary stream of objects in java is. Still, if this would require me to spend days on learning the intrinsics of java, this wouldn't be an option for me.

Comment: This really doesn't matter for anything other than my own curiosity, but what custom UDP protocol are you using? Did you roll your own, or are you using something like UDT (udt.sourceforge.net)?

Comment: It's my own protocol built on top of UDP. It adds some TCP features, to be precise it ensures message integrity, re-requests missing packages, and allows message handlers to optionally enforce package ordering at runtime. It's built specifically for games. As far as I know UDT specializes in a different area, however the lidgren library for C# seems to be similar to what I roll.

Comment: That's pretty interesting. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're interested in RPC, there is always [XML-RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC) and [JSON-RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC), both of which have free/open-source C++ implementations. Unfortunately, most of my development has been in Java, so I can't speak to how usable or effective they are, but it might be something to look into since it sounds like you have already done some work in C++ and are comfortable with it. They also have Java implementations, so you might even be able to support both Java and C++ applications with XML-RPC or JSON-RPC, if you want to go down that route.

The only downside is that it looks like most of these use HTTP connections. One of the things you wanted to do was to reuse the existing connection. Now, I haven't looked at all of the implementations, but the two that I looked at might not meet that requirement. Worst case is that perhaps you can get some ideas. Best case if that there might be another implementation out there somewhere that does what you need and you now have a starting point to find it.

Answer (score 1):

The use of RPCs as an abstraction do not preclude the use of UDP as the transport layer: RMI is an RPC abstraction that generally used TCP under the hood (last time I looked).

I'd suggest just coding up a Java layer to talk your UDP protocol: you can use any one of many libraries to do it and you don't have to discard all your existing work. If you want to wrap an RPC layer around your protocol no reason why you can't do that: create a `login` method that sends the login UDP packet and receives the appropriate response and returns it.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, but having no experience with Java, I seem to be unable to find the right documentation/libraries. Could you point me at a resource to learn more?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a remotely serious project, you should probably take a look at [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty).

It's a great library for developing networked systems, has a lot of proven production usage and is well suited for things like TCP or UDP client-server communication. I wouldn't go reinventing this wheel unless you really have to :-)

As a bonus they have some good examples and documentation too.

Comment: The library looks interesting, but I couldn't find any mention of RPCs. Furthermore, I only want two "encodings", binary and serialized objects, so a complete pipeline for decoding/encoding seems overkill to me.